# REGEX validate MAC and delimeters

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate **MAC address** and allow to use only one kind of delimiter.
I use pattern :

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

It works fine, but there is some bug.
For example: `01-23:45:67:89-AB` is valid according pattern. How to allow use only one kind of delimiter ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?=([:-]))(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB6WNi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` - two hex chars
- `(?=([:-]))` - the next char must  be a `:` or `-`, this value is captured into Group 1
- `(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}` - exactly five occurrences of

  - `\1` - the same char that is stored in Group 1 buffer
  - `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` - two hex chars
- `$` - end of string.

Alternatively, to shorten the pattern a bit, you may also use

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(?=([:-]))(?:\2(?1)){5}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB6WNi/2). You may also use a case insensitive modifier to "shrink" it even more: `'~^([0-9A-F]{2})(?=([:-]))(?:\2(?1)){5}$~i'`. The thing is that the first part of the pattern, `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})`, is captured, and `(?1)` recurses the pattern later (so that you do not need to write it again).